# How to fill nan values in a data frame's column with a value from the same column when both share the equal value in another column? Ex: Where clause

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-cleaning

I am a very beginner in python and need your help with my problem here.
I have a dataset regarding coronavirus mortality. There are 2 columns Neighborhood Name (Column Name: Neighbourhood Name)which based on Postal Code Column (Column Name: NFS, and The postal code column which filled based on the Neighborhood Name column.

I am trying to fill the Nan values in both columns.

Here What I tried to do.

1 - getting the data into jupyter

```
 covid_df.head(5)
```

[Output is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WivA0.png)

```
covid_df.isnull().sum().to_frame()
```

[Null Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxpZ3.png)

```
covid_sub_df = covid_df.loc[:, ['Neighbourhood Name', 'FSA']]
covid_sub_df

covid_sub_df_2 = covid_sub_df.drop_duplicates()
covid_sub_df_2
```

Now I tried This

```
val = ""
for i, j in covid_df['Neighbourhood Name'], covid_df['FSA']:
    for k,l in covid_sub_df_2['Neighbourhood Name'], covid_sub_df_2['FSA']:
        if k == val and j == l:
            covid_df['Neighbourhood Name'] = covid_sub_df['Neighbourhood Name']
        if j == val and k == i:
            covid_df['FSA'] = covid_sub_df['FSA']
```

I get this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 val = ""
> ----> 2 for i, j in covid_df['Neighbourhood Name'], covid_df['FSA']:
> 3     for k,l in covid_sub_df_2['Neighbourhood Name'], covid_sub_df_2['FSA']:
> 4         if k == val and j == l:
> 5             covid_df['Neighbourhood Name'] = covid_sub_df['Neighbourhood Name']
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Thank You all

Comment: I think you should edit your main question and pose what you want to do with every line of code you wrote. You can also add comments with # in front of every line and explain what you are doing or want to do. The way you have posed your problem is not abundantly clear. Also refer this to formulate your question better https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is get rid of the following error?

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

The question isn't posed very specifically because the title is how to fill nan values. Also, you should try and provide a dummy data if possible

However, assuming you want to get rid of the error, it is possible you wanted to simultaneously loop over the variables. There is a function called as `zip()` that does that. So the following modification should hopefully work:

```
val = ""
for i, j in zip(covid_df['Neighbourhood Name'], covid_df['FSA']):
    for k,l in zip(covid_sub_df_2['Neighbourhood Name'], covid_sub_df_2['FSA']):
        if k == val and j == l:
            covid_df['Neighbourhood Name'] = covid_sub_df['Neighbourhood Name']
        if j == val and k == i:
            covid_df['FSA'] = covid_sub_df['FSA']
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is my first use of the website.
I tried your modifications and the code worked, but no change happened to the data frame, I am still getting the nan values.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand do you want to fill with nan values or get rid of it. In your question, the last line says I am trying to fill nan values in both columns.

Comment: I am trying to remove all the nan values from both columns and replace them with their values based on the values in the same column. 

for example:

1st column is Neighborhood name
second Column: first 3 letters of postal code
Each observation is filled based on the value of the other column

So, If I want to fill postal code nan values, I need to get the value based on the Neighborhood name which found in another observation with a needed postal code value,

That is the problem I am trying to solve.
Thank you

Comment: Please check my comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which values you want to fill your Nan values with. One option is to use pandas DataFrame replace method:

```
covid_df.replace({np.nan : new_value})
```

replaces every nan value with that new_value. This works beacause pandas is built on top of numpy, a famous python library, and saves every Nan value as a np.nan. You should import numpy for this to work previously:

```
import numpy as np
```

Be aware that every Nan value will be replaced with the same exact value in the new_value variable.